# canvas is stretching when changing device type in dev tool

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have next canvas with some content:

```js
class ExpectedLifespanRound {
    constructor() {
      // max lifespan that is possible
      this.lifespanMax = 125
     
      // expected lifespan block
      this.expLsBlock = document.getElementById("expected-lifespan-block")
      
      // set style for the block
      this.style = this.expLsBlock.style
      this.style.padding = "20px"
      this.style.display = "flex"
      this.style.width  = "320px"
      this.style.height = "406px"
      this.style.borderRadius = "20px"
      this.style.backgroundColor = "white"

      // set canvas style
      this.can = this.initCanvas("expected-lifespan-block")
      this.can.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      // - 40 is padding
      this.can.style.width = this.expLsBlock.outerWidth - 40 + "px"
      this.can.style.height =this.expLsBlock.outerHeight - 40 + "px"
      this.can.style.marginLeft = "8px"
      this.expLsBlock.appendChild(this.can);
      this.ctx = this.can.getContext("2d")
      // set gradient for arc
      this.gradient = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(320, 0, 0, 406);
      this.gradient.addColorStop("0.3", "#ABB8FF")
      this.gradient.addColorStop("0.7" ,"#ABF0FF")
    }
    clearCanvas() {
      // clear canvas
      this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 406)
      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
      this.ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
      this.ctx.closePath();
    }
    create(years) {
      // title
      this.ctx.save()
      this.clearCanvas()
      this.ctx.fillStyle = "black"
      this.ctx.font = "bolder 18px Arial";
      this.ctx.fillText("Ожидаемая", 100, 30)
      this.ctx.fillText("продолжительность жизни", 32, 56)
      this.ctx.restore()
      // arc
      this.ctx.save()
      this.ctx.fillStyle = this.gradient
      this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.gradient
      this.ctx.lineWidth = 35
      this.ctx.arc(150, 250, 125, Math.PI - (1.5 * Math.PI/this.lifespanMax)*years, 1.5 * Math.PI)
      this.ctx.font = "bold 55px Arial"
      var x = 120
      if (years >= 100) {x = 105}
      this.ctx.fillText(years, x, 245)
      this.ctx.font = "bold 36px Arial"
      this.ctx.fillText("лет", 120, 285)
      this.ctx.stroke()
      this.ctx.restore()
    }
    refresh(years) {
      this.create(years)
    }
    initCanvas(blockForCanvas) {
        // create high dpi canvas and put it in the block

        // return pixel ratio
        var getRatio = function () {
          var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
          var dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
          var bsr =
            ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
            ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
            ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
            ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
            ctx.backingStorePixelRatio ||
            1;
  
          return dpr / bsr;
        };
        // return high dots per inch canvas
        var createHiDPICanvas = function (w, h) {
          var ratio = getRatio();
          var chart_container = document.getElementById(blockForCanvas);
          var can = document.createElement("canvas");
          can.style.backgroundColor = "white";
          can.width = 320 * ratio;
          can.height = 406 * ratio;
          can.style.width = w + "px";
          can.style.height = h + "px";
          can.getContext("2d").setTransform(ratio, 0, 0, ratio, 0, 0);
          chart_container.appendChild(can);
          return can;
        }
        var canvas = createHiDPICanvas(this.scaleWidth, this.scaleHeight)
        return canvas
     }
  }
  
  var expLsRound = new ExpectedLifespanRound()
  expLsRound.create(95)
```

```css
body {
    background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="expected-lifespan-block"></div>
```

It is ok on my `1920x1080` screen, but when I switch type to mobile (line iphone 6, ipad or any other) - it is strating to stretch in not appropriate way. You can test it in chrome dev tools, or take a look on the pictures I tave taken:

normal:

[image]

stretched after switching to another device using dev tools:

[image]

How to avoid such a stretching and let this canvas be the same size no depending what device screen user has?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to replace 2 functions out if innerCanvas function and it does not stretch anymore